# How to read the single header value when it contains special characters in Ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I need to read the "X-JWT-Assertion" with the request.

Usually, we could use the following technique to read "Connection" header parameter.

```
resource function get menu(@http:Header string Connection) returns json {}
```

But when the header value contains special characters, it gives an error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4fEV.png)

```
resource function get menu(@http:Header string X-JWT-Assertion) returns json {}
```

How to use refer to values with special characters in parameters in the resource definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\` to escape `-`.

E.g.,

```
import ballerina/http;

service on new http:Listener(8080) {
    resource function get menu(@http:Header string X\-JWT\-Assertion) returns json {

    }
}
```

Ballerina example - [Identifiers](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/identifiers/)